# How to reject mobile calls for a time duration in android

Tags: android, phone-call, telephonymanager

How can I block mobile calls for a time duration of 1 hour which I will set, I have tried the following code, I am not aware how to schedule the broadcast receiver for a time duration.

```
public class RejectCall extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ITelephony telephonyService;
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        try {
            Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            String phoneNumber = bundle.getString("incoming_number");
            Log.d("INCOMING", phoneNumber);
            if ((phoneNumber != null)) {
                telephonyService.endCall();
                Log.d("HANG UP", phoneNumber);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```